# Oracle: select * from (select table_name from ... )?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a query that returns the name of tables, is it possible to evaluate the name and use it in a subsequent query?

E.G.

```
select count(1) from x where x in 
    (select table_name from ALL_TABLES where table_name like 'MY_TABLE_%');
```

Obviously this is invalid syntax, but it should illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in a single select statement.  But if you just want to count the number of rows per table : `ALL_TABLES.NUM_ROWS`.

Comment: That almost worked like a charm! Unfortunately I'm trying to get the depth of selected queue tables, and they have their num_rows values as null.

Comment: Yeah that should prove tricky if you want it in one select statement.  Can you not break it up into a loop?

Comment: That's what I have done. Cheers.

Comment: `all_tables.num_rows` is populated when stats are gathered on the tables, so may be useful if you just want a reasonable estimate.

Comment: can you enforce stat collection on queue tables? Or is there an easier way to get queue depth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, but it requires that you resort to an [XML query](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/04/how-do-i-store-the-counts-of-all-tables.html).

```
select
       table_name,
       to_number(
         extractvalue(
           xmltype(
             dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c ' ||
                                ' from '||owner||'.'||table_name))
           ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
   from all_tables
  where table_name like 'MY_TABLE_%'
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use something like

```
select table_name
into table_name_value
from ALL_TABLES where table_name like 'MY_TABLE_%');

execute immediate 'select count(1) from ' || table_name_value into returned_value;
```

and adopt it into your loop